# onMouseOver change background image position

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to reposition the background image of a div using javascript. Here's what I have but it doesn't seem to work. What am I missing?

```
<a href="#" onMouseOver="document.getElementById('rubbish_image').style.backgroundPosition="0px 150px"">link one</a>
<a href="#" onMouseOver="document.getElementById('rubbish_image').style.backgroundPosition="0px 350px"">link two</a>

<div id="rubbish_image"></a>
```

Comment: You realise you have **two** quotes before the closing `>` of the `a` tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure, but there's *two* obvious problems I can see with your JavaScript:

1. You've got **two** `"` just before the closing `>` of the `a` tags, as a result of
2. Your use of `"` *inside of* the string, which isn't allowed (you can use `'` inside a string delimited with `"`, or vice versa, but `"` inside of a string delimited by `"` terminates the string).

I'd suggest, therefore, amending the code to:

```
<a href="#" onMouseOver="document.getElementById('rubbish_image').style.backgroundPosition='0px 150px';">link one</a>
<a href="#" onMouseOver="document.getElementById('rubbish_image').style.backgroundPosition='0px 350px';">link two</a>
```

I don't believe it's a huge problem, but you also didn't terminate your JavaScript within the `onmouseover` attribute, so I also added the `;` to the end of each.

Answer (score 1):

You're nesting double quotes, which won't work.

A simple fix is to only use single quotes inside the `onmouseover` attributes:

```
<a href="#" onMouseOver="document.getElementById('rubbish_image').style.backgroundPosition='0px 150px'">link one</a>
<a href="#" onMouseOver="document.getElementById('rubbish_image').style.backgroundPosition='0px 350px'">link two</a>

<div id="rubbish_image"></a>
```

You're already doing this inside `getElementById`.